# Drawing chips from a bag

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables

A bag with contains $5$ chips that are either red or blue chips. The number of red chips is a random variable $X$ where $X$ can be either $2, 3$ or $4$ with equal probability. Given that when $5$ chips are drawn with replacement, the result is: $3$ of the draws are red and $2$ are blue, what is the conditional probability that $X = 4$?

My attempt:

Consider Bayes Theorem: $P(X = 4 | 3 red, 2 blue) = \frac{P(X = 4 \land 3 red, 2 blue)}{P(3 red, 2 blue)} = \frac{P(3 red, 2 blue | X = 4) \cdot P(X = 4)}{P(3 red, 2 blue)}$.

Assume $X = 4$ (then there are 4 reds and 1 blue) and let $Y$ be the number of red chips drawn. $Y$ is binomial with $n = 5$ and $p = \frac{4}{5}$. So $P(Y = 3) = 0.2048$ (by applying the binomial function). So $P(3 red, 2 blue | X = 4) = 0.2048)$.

Clearly $P(X = 4)$ = $\frac{1}{3}$.

All that remains in to determine $P(3 red, 2 blue)$. I tried this:

If $X = 2$ let $Z$ be the number of red chips drawn ($Z$ is binomial with $n = 5$ and $p = \frac{2}{5}$) and then $P(Z = 3) = 0.2304$

If $X = 3$ let $Z$ be the number of red chips drawn ($Z$ is binomial with $n = 5$ and $p = \frac{3}{5}$) and then $P(Z = 3) = 0.3456$

If $X = 4$, we already saw that $P(Z = 3) = 0.2048$.

So $P(3 red, 2 blue) = 0.2304 + 0.3456 + 0.2048 = 0.7808$

Plugging in the appropriate probabilities shows that $P(X = 4 | 3 red, 2 blue) = \frac{0.2048 \cdot \frac{1}{3}}{0.7808} \approx 0.0874$

Did I do this correctly? This is practice for an upcoming examination and no solutions are available. Whatever help I can get is appreciated.

Comment: Conduct a sanity check re consistency of numerator and denominator.

Comment: @trueblueanil What do you mean by that?

Comment: Why have you multiplied only the numerator by 1/3 ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Because $P(X = 4) = \frac{1}{3}$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct but you made a mistake in calculation. Also I will suggest that your working should be using fractions instead of converting into decimals.

If $Y$ is the event of $3$ red and $2$ blue in $5$ draws with replacement,

$\small P(X = 4 | Y) = \displaystyle \frac{P(X = 4 \ \cap \ Y)}{P(Y)}$

$\small P(Y) = P(X=2 \cap Y) + P(X=3 \cap Y) + P(X=4 \cap Y)$

$ = \displaystyle \small \frac{1}{3} \cdot {5 \choose 3} \cdot \big[\big(\frac{2}{5}\big)^3 \big(\frac{3}{5}\big)^2 + \big(\frac{3}{5}\big)^3 \big(\frac{2}{5}\big)^2 + \big(\frac{4}{5}\big)^3 \big(\frac{1}{5}\big)^2\big]$

$\small P(X=4 \cap Y) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{3} \cdot {5 \choose 3} \cdot \big(\frac{4}{5}\big)^3 \big(\frac{1}{5}\big)^2$

$\small P(X = 4 | Y) = \displaystyle \frac{16}{61}$

Comment: So what I had calculated to be my $P(3 red, 2 blue | X = 4)$ was actually $P(3 red, 2 blue \cap X = 4)$?

Comment: Same thing. $P(3R,2B \cap X = 4) = P(3R, 2B|X=4) \cdot P(X=4)$. So you found that correctly. The mistake was in your denominator.